# jQuery multi-step form: disable next button when fields unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a multi-step form that has a "next" and "back" button on each step of the form. I'm using jQuery to enable the "next" button once the criteria for each section is met. For example: at least one checkbox is checked or a radio button is selected.

I'm having an issue where after completing a number of sections, I go back to a previous section and uncheck all checkboxes and the "next" button remains enabled.

There's a Codepen here of a rough version of what I'm working with - note all sections are visible to show how the button remains enabled once you begin checking/unchecking: https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/jZgQOV

My current code:

```
<form>
    <fieldset class="panels">
        <h2>1: Select multiple answers</h2>
        <label for="checkbox-1">Checkbox 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox-2">Checkbox 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" name="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox-3">Checkbox 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" name="checkbox" />
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="next-q" disabled>Next</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="panels">
        <h2>2: Select multiple answers</h2>
        <label for="checkbox-4">Checkbox 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-4" name="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox-5">Checkbox 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-5" name="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox-6">Checkbox 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-6" name="checkbox" />
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="next-q" disabled>Next</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="panels">
        <h2>3: Select one answer</h2>
        <label for="radio-1">Radio 1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="radio" />
        <label for="radio-2">Radio 2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio" />
        <label for="radio-2">Radio 3</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="radio" />
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="next-q" disabled>Next</button>
        <button type="button" class="previous-q">Previous</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="rows">
        <h2>4: Select one answer per row</h2>
        <div class="radio-row">
            <h3>Row 1</h3>
            <label for="radio-4">Radio 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-4" name="radio-row-1" />
            <label for="radio-5">Radio 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-5" name="radio-row-1" />
            <label for="radio-6">Radio 3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-6" name="radio-row-1" />
        </div>
        <div class="radio-row">
            <h3>Row 2</h3>
            <label for="radio-7">Radio 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-7" name="radio-row-2" />
            <label for="radio-8">Radio 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-8" name="radio-row-2" />
            <label for="radio-9">Radio 3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-9" name="radio-row-2" />
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="next-q" disabled>Next</button>
        <button type="button" class="previous-q">Previous</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var $panelsInput = $('.panels input'),
        $rowsInput = $('.rows input');

$panelsInput.click(function () {
  if ($('.panels input:checked').length >= 1) {
    $(this).closest('.panels').find('.next-q').prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else {
    $(this).closest('.panels').find('.next-q').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});

$rowsInput.click(function () {
    var radioLength = $('.radio-row').length;
    if ($('.rows input:checked').length == radioLength) {
        $('.rows .next-q').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $('.rows .next-q').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you select the input to see if is checked, you're selecting all inputs

`if ($('.panels input:checked').length >= 1) {`

you need to select just the inputs from the panel the user clicked

`if ($(this).closest('.panels').find('input:checked').length >= 1) {`

https://codepen.io/spacedog4/pen/YaWqdo?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

Please see below comment in `$panelsInput.click(function (){});`, you need to get the `checked` count for **current panel** (the user clicks), instead of all.

So the comparasion in your codes:
`$('.panels input:checked').length >= 1`

need to change to:
`$(this).parent().find('input:checked').length >= 1`

```js
var $panelsInput = $('.panels input'),
    $rowsInput = $('.rows input');

$panelsInput.click(function () {
  //get current input, find out its parent, then get the count of checked
  if ($(this).parent().find('input:checked').length >= 1) {
    $(this).closest('.panels').find('.next-q').prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else {
    $(this).closest('.panels').find('.next-q').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});

$rowsInput.click(function () {
    var radioLength = $('.radio-row').length;
    if ($('.rows input:checked').length == radioLength) {
        $('.rows .next-q').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $('.rows .next-q').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset class="panels">
    <h2>1: Select multiple answers</h2>
    <label for="checkbox-1">Checkbox 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox-2">Checkbox 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" name="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox-3">Checkbox 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" name="checkbox" />
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="next-q" disabled>Next</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="panels">
    <h2>2: Select multiple answers</h2>
    <label for="checkbox-4">Checkbox 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-4" name="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox-5">Checkbox 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-5" name="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox-6">Checkbox 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-6" name="checkbox" />
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="next-q" disabled>Next</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="panels">
    <h2>3: Select one answer</h2>
    <label for="radio-1">Radio 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="radio" />
    <label for="radio-2">Radio 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio" />
    <label for="radio-2">Radio 3</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="radio" />
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="next-q" disabled>Next</button>
    <button type="button" class="previous-q">Previous</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="rows">
    <h2>4: Select one answer per row</h2>
    <div class="radio-row">
      <h3>Row 1</h3>
      <label for="radio-4">Radio 1</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio-4" name="radio-row-1" />
      <label for="radio-5">Radio 2</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio-5" name="radio-row-1" />
      <label for="radio-6">Radio 3</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio-6" name="radio-row-1" />
    </div>
    <div class="radio-row">
      <h3>Row 2</h3>
      <label for="radio-7">Radio 1</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio-7" name="radio-row-2" />
      <label for="radio-8">Radio 2</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio-8" name="radio-row-2" />
      <label for="radio-9">Radio 3</label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio-9" name="radio-row-2" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="next-q" disabled>Next</button>
    <button type="button" class="previous-q">Previous</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice! Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it is interesting to handle interactions using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) at the `form` level which is more flexible:

- Only one handler is loaded in memory. (By the way only a single scope is in charge of the logic behind the prev/next behavior).
- You can add dynamically panels to the form (with the same markup structure) and buttons will work right away without requiring another listener registering step.

```js
var $panelsInput = $('.panels input')
    , $rowsInput = $('.rows input')
    ;

$('form').on('click', function (e) {
   let $t = $(this)
       , $target = $(e.target)
       , $fieldset = $target.closest('fieldset')
       , $rows = $fieldset.find('.radio-row')
       ;
       
   // When a button is clicked
   if ($target.is('button')) {
     // Next button
     if ($target.is('.next-q')) {
         $fieldset.addClass('hide').next().addClass('show');
     // Prev button
     } else {
        // Untick boxes
        $fieldset.find('input').prop('checked', false).end()
        // Disable appropriate button
        .find('.next-q').prop('disabled', true).end()
        .prev().removeClass('hide').nextAll().removeClass('show');
        
     }
     
   // When a checkbox is clicked
   } else if ($target.is('input')) {
        let $containers = ($rows.length ? $rows : $fieldset)
            , containersHavingAtickedBox = $containers.filter(function() {
              return !!$(this).find('input:checked').length
            })
            , shouldEnable = $containers.length === containersHavingAtickedBox.length
            ;
        $fieldset.find('.next-q').prop('disabled', !shouldEnable);
   }
});
```

```css
fieldset ~ fieldset, .hide{display:none}
fieldset.show:not(.hide){display: block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <fieldset class="panels">
        <h2>1: Select multiple answers</h2>
        <label for="checkbox-1">Checkbox 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox-2">Checkbox 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" name="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox-3">Checkbox 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" name="checkbox" />
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="next-q" disabled>Next</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="panels">
        <h2>2: Select multiple answers</h2>
        <label for="checkbox-4">Checkbox 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-4" name="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox-5">Checkbox 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-5" name="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox-6">Checkbox 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-6" name="checkbox" />
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="next-q" disabled>Next</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="panels">
        <h2>3: Select one answer</h2>
        <label for="radio-1">Radio 1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="radio" />
        <label for="radio-2">Radio 2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio" />
        <label for="radio-2">Radio 3</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="radio" />
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="next-q" disabled>Next</button>
        <button type="button" class="previous-q">Previous</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="rows">
        <h2>4: Select one answer per row</h2>
        <div class="radio-row">
            <h3>Row 1</h3>
            <label for="radio-4">Radio 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-4" name="radio-row-1" />
            <label for="radio-5">Radio 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-5" name="radio-row-1" />
            <label for="radio-6">Radio 3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-6" name="radio-row-1" />
        </div>
        <div class="radio-row">
            <h3>Row 2</h3>
            <label for="radio-7">Radio 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-7" name="radio-row-2" />
            <label for="radio-8">Radio 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-8" name="radio-row-2" />
            <label for="radio-9">Radio 3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio-9" name="radio-row-2" />
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="next-q" disabled>Next</button>
        <button type="button" class="previous-q">Previous</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```